# jQuery - Radio button is checked

Tags: jquery

I have these two radio buttons. I want to do, so whenever a user selects one, then jQuery should show the `div` that has the content for that button. Example `#paypal` has a `div` called `#mydivpaypal` and `#payza` has a `div` called `#mydivpayza`.

Whenever a user clicks on `#paypal`, I want only `#mydivpaypal` to show. The goes with `#payza`.

**HTML:**

```
<ul class="payment-methods" id="pmethods" style="margin-left:320px;">
  <li class="payment-method paypal">
    <input name="payment_methods" type="radio" id="paypal">
    <label for="paypal">PayPal</label>
  </li> 
  <li class="payment-method payza">
    <input name="payment_methods" type="radio" id="pagseguro">
    <label for="pagseguro">PagSeguro</label>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var boxes = $('input:checked');
$(boxes).each(function() {
   if($('#paypal').is(':checked')) { 
    $("#mydivpaypal").show();
    }
   if($('#payza').is(':checked')) { 
    $("#mydivpaypal").hide();
       $("#mydivpayza").show();
    }
});
```

I can't get this to work. Nothing happens when the radio buttons are checked.

Comment: Check your `divs` **IDs**, they don't exist in your posted **HTML**. Also, use [.change()](http://api.jquery.com/change/) insead of `.each()`.

Comment: I haven't printed them in this code. They do exist.

Comment: have you binded onChange or onClick event on you radio buttons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code can't do anything because with an [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) you are iterating over the checked radio and setting, eventually, its first visibility state; without any event listener to your radio button [`change`](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event the code will not run when you change the selected radio option.

Use the event **change**:

> Description: Bind an event handler to the "change" JavaScript event,
>   or trigger that event on an element.

Second in your HTML there is no `payza` id but `pagseguro`, and remember to alternatively hide/show the div according to the current checked radio.

Code:

```
$('input[name=payment_methods]').change(function () {
    if ($('#paypal').is(':checked')) {
        $("#mydivpayza").hide();
        $("#mydivpaypal").show();
    }
    if ($('#pagseguro').is(':checked')) {
        $("#mydivpaypal").hide();
        $("#mydivpayza").show();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/NVsPj/

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  your `second radio id` is **pagseguro** not **payza**

Try it like,

```
$('input#paypal').on('click',function() {
    $("#mydivpayza").hide();
    $("#mydivpaypal").show();     
});
$('input#pagseguro').on('click',function() {
    $("#mydivpaypal").hide();
    $("#mydivpayza").show();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FKL8A/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to place it all under change event... Kind of:

```
$('input[name=payment_methods]').change(function(){
    if($('#paypal').is(':checked')) { 
        $("#mydivpaypal").show();
    }
    if($('#payza').is(':checked')) { 
        $("#mydivpaypal").hide();
        $("#mydivpayza").show();
    }
})
```

Here is some better idea of hot to do it nicely and shortly... on Fiddle

```
   $('.payment-method input').change(function(){
        $('#'+this.id+'_div').show().siblings().hide()
    })
```

http://jsfiddle.net/acrashik/Nt7nS/

Answer (score 0):

With your current code you don't have any event listener waiting for the radio button to be clicked. Your code is only running when the page is loaded. You just need to add an event listener to check the radio buttons when they're clicked

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/adambotley/2h8vW/

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var boxes = $('input:checked');
    $(boxes).click( function(){ 
        $(boxes).each(function() {
           if($('#paypal').is(':checked')) { 
            $("#mydivpaypal").show();
            }
           if($('#payza').is(':checked')) { 
            $("#mydivpaypal").hide();
               $("#mydivpayza").show();
            }
        });
});
```

By adding a .click() listener, it will check for the :checked state whenever either radio is clicked